# Running VMware Workstation in background with a Unity-enabled VM?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, vmware-unity

How can I dismiss the taskbar button for VMware Workstation (8) on Windows when running a VM in Unity mode? For other VMs I can simply close the VMware GUI and tell it to "Run in background". When I do it for a VM running in Unity mode, the Unity mode gets switched off and next time I connect to the VMware GUI again the guest ends up in a resolution stretching beyond both my screens.

Any ideas how to run the guest/VM in Unity mode while running it in background? If there is a scripting option (VIX API), that's fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: VMWare team [confirmed it's by design](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/260672?start=0&tstart=0) (although poor design if you ask me).

But you can use a small program to [send the window to Tray](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rbtray/files/rbtray/4.3/RBTray-4_3.zip/download) after you start Unity. Not ideal, but better than nothing.